# Android - Unlocking phone with voice

Tags: java, android, eclipse, voice-recognition, android-wake-lock

Is it possible to unlock phone with voice command, even when device is in PowerManager.WakeLock mode?I thought of using Service as background process but can phone device react when locked?Any ideas?

ps.Just to be clear I'm using Java Android SDK

Comment: This is not a programming but a user question.

Comment: I think it's more a bad written question.

Comment: I dont think there is any problem in question , should not be closed , If you guys dont have answers ,Just not react negatively on that.

Answer (score 2):

See [CMUSphinx on Android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid), it may can help you .