# Android Speech Recognition behind lock screen

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm using googles voice recognition to gather a response from a user. My application wakes up and 'speaks' to the user (while the device is still locked). At this point I want to receive a voice command from behind the lock screen and use it to do stuff in the background without the user having to touch the phone. What is happening at the moment is that the waking up and text-to-speech stuff is fine, but the speech recognizer won't recognise speech from behind the lock screen. Is this possible?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Unlocking phone with voice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773755/android-unlocking-phone-with-voice)

Comment: Basically you can try Pocketsphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) is a real solution for this problem. To achieve this using google speech recognition api, you might have to resort to continuous speech recognition which takes too much resources and drains the device battery.

On the other hand, Pocketsphinx works really great. It's fast enough to spot a key phrase and recognize voice commands behind the lock screen without users touching their device. And it does all this offline.
 You can try the [demo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-android-demo-5prealpha.tar.gz/download).